# How to use parentheses correctly?

Tags: python, string, boolean-expression

Why does it work differently?

```py
p='/content/Images_of_Waste/img/PET968.txt'
p[-3:]!='txt' and p[-3:]!='jpg'
False
```

```py
p[-3:]!=('txt' and 'jpg')
True
```

How can I use parentheses correctly?

Comment: Try setting `x=('txt' and 'jpg')`. Whatever that evaluates to is the value you're testing in your `p[-3:]!=x` which I'd imagine are not equal.

Comment: ```p[-3:] not in ('txt', 'jpg')```

Comment: You can always use the handy [operator precedence table](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) in the fine documentation to determine whether they're needed and where to place them in expressions.

Comment: Python doesn't support any kind of operator distribution. `x*(y+z)` is only *semantically* equivalent to `x*y + x*z` due to the definitions of `*` and `+`, not *operationally* equivalent. (That is, Python evaluates `y + z`, then multiplies the result by `x`; it does not first transform the expression into the sum of two products.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, non-empty strings are effectively `True`.

That is to say,

```
if 'txt':
    # this code will execute
```

As the @gimix mentions below, however,

```
if 'txt' == True:
    # this code will not execute
```

In terms of `('txt' and 'jpg')`, `'txt'` is not `False`, and neither is `'jpg'`, thus, `('txt' and 'jpg')` evaluates to `'jpg'` per @Manish's comment.

Comment: This is not totally correct... `('txt' and 'jpg')` evaluates to `'jpg'`; and even if `'jpg'` would evaluate to `True` in something like `if 'jpg':` this is still not the actual `True` constant value: `'jpg' == True` returns False

Comment: Quoting from docs.python.org(https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) : 
```The expression x and y first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.```

Answer (score 0):

```
if p[-3:] not in ('txt', 'jpg'):
    # Do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p='/content/Images_of_Waste/img/PET968.txt'
p[-3:]!='txt' and p[-3:]!='jpg'
```

An important point to note: (from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#and))

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

In here, `p[-3:]` gives `txt`. When you compare it to `p[-3:]!='txt' and p[-3:]!='jpg'`, the first condition returns `False` as `p[-3:]` is indeed `txt`. And according to the documentation, if `x` evaluated to `False`, its value is returned. So you get `False`

---

Another point to note in operator precedence (from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence))
You can see in the operator precedence that the following is evaluated first:

> Binding or parenthesized expression, list display, dictionary display, set display.

The expression enclosed in brackets are given the first precedence and are evaluated first.

```
p[-3:]!=('txt' and 'jpg')
```

In this case, `('txt' and 'jpg')` is evaluated first. **Any *non-empty* string in python has truthy value**. So the first operand evaluates to `True` because it has 3 elements: `t,x,t`. And going back to the line where * if `x` is false, its value is returned; ...`,` y`is evaluated. So`y``` is `png` which is a *non-empty* string.

This python will evaluate the las operand and return the resulting value, which here is `True`.

Of course `p[-3:]!=True` is `True` and `True` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

In second part when you do `('txt' and 'jpg')`, it evaluates to `'jpg'`.

So effectively, you are trying to do is:

```
p[-3:] != 'jpg'
```

and since `p[-3:]` evaluates to 'txt'

therefore,

```
p[-3:] != ('txt' and 'jpg')
```

evaluates to True.

In the first part:

```
p='/content/Images_of_Waste/img/PET968.txt'
p[-3:]!='txt' and p[-3:]!='jpg'
```

`p[-3:]!='txt'` return True
`p[-3:]!='jpg'` return False

therefore,
`True` and `False` return False